# open link in same page with js

Tags: javascript, html

My problem is that i cannot open another link in same page with my info, if i use www.example.com/?town it wont read my info page, but if i opened with ony www.example.com/# it will read it

**Table1 is not working, table2 is working...**

Is there a possibility to make a select  with link in page

```js
function show(nr) {
    document.getElementById("table1").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table2").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table3").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table4").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table5").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table6").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table7").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table8").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table9").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table10").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table11").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table12").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table13").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table14").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table15").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table16").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table17").style.display="none";
 document.getElementById("table18").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("table"+nr).style.display="block";
}
```

```css
td {vertical-align: top;}
#table1, #table2, #table3, #table4, #table5,#table6, #table7, #table8, #table9, #table10, #table11, #table12, #table13, #table14, #table15, #table16, #table17, #table18 {display: none; padding:5px;}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
   <a href="?bucuresti" onclick='show(1);'>București</a>
            <br />
            <a href="#" onclick='show(2);'>Arad</a>
            <br />
            <a href="#" onclick='show(3);'>Covasna</a>
            <br />
            <a href="#" onclick='show(4);'>Craiova</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(5);'>Târgu Mureş</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(6);'>Brăila</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(7);'>Oradea</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(8);'>Râmnicul Vâlcea</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(9);'>Satu-Mare</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(10);'>Slatina</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(11);'>Galaţi</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(12);'>Cluj-Napoca</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(13);'>Timișoara</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(14);'>Brașov</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(15);'>Iași</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(16);'>Ploiești</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(17);'>Bacău</a>
   <br />
   <a href="#" onclick='show(18);'>Slobozia</a>
  
            
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="table1"> <table border="1"><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td><td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b></td><td><b>Centre de prelevare</b></td><td><b>Centre de transplant</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS București<br />
Str. Dr. C-tin Caracaş nr. 2-8, Sect. 1, Bucureşti<br />
Telefon: 031 425 1241<br />
Fax: 021 319 3162<br /><br />
Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Spitalul Clinic de Urgență București<br />
Calea Floreasca nr . 8, Sector 1, Bucureşti<br />
Telefon: 021 599 2300<br />
Fax: 021 599 2257<br /><br />
Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Spitalul Universitar de Urgență București<br />
Splaiul Independentei Nr.169, Sector 5, Bucureşti<br />
Telefon: 021 318 0519<br /><br />
Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Institutul Clinic Fundeni<br />
Șoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti<br />
Telefon: 021 318 0448<br />
Fax: 021 318 0444</td><td>Laboratorul de histocompatibilitate <br />
Institutul National de Hematologie Transfuzionala “Prof.Dr.C.T.Nicolau” București<br />
Strada Constantin Caracaș Nr. 2-8, Sector 1, Bucureșt<br />
Telefon: 031 425 1230/31/32/33 interior 215<br />
Fax:        021 319 1779<br />
Instit. de Hematologie – www.transfuzia.ro<br /><br />
Laboratorul central de referință pentru virusurile transmise prin sânge<br />
Institutul Național de Hematologie Transfuzională București<br />
Strada Constantin Caracaș, Nr. 2-8, Sector 1, București<br />
Telefon: 031 425 1230/47 interior 232<br />
Instit. de Hematologie – www.transfuzia.ro</td><td>Institutul Clinic Fundeni, Bucureşti<br />
Şoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti, 022328<br />
Telefon: 021 275 0700<br />
Fax:       021 318 0444<br />
www.icfundeni.ro</td><td>Institutul Clinic Fundeni Bucureşti<br />
Şoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti, 022328<br />
Telefon: 021 275 0700<br />
Fax:       021 318 0444<br />
www.icfundeni.ro</td></table></div>
            <div id="table2"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Arad<br />
Str. Spitalului Nr. 4, Arad<br />
Telefon: 0357 432 914; 0357 432 915<br />
Fax: 0357 432 914; 0357 432 915</td></tr></table></div>
            <div id="table3"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Covasna<br />
Str. Banki Donath 15, Covasna<br />
Telefon: 0367 401 164 ; 0367 401 165<br />
Fax: 0267 311 980</td></tr></table></div>
            <div id="table4"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Craiova
Str. Tabaci, Nr. 1, Dolj<br />
Telefon: 0351432 059; 0351 432 060<br />
Fax: 0251 411 633<br />
Fax: 0267 311 980</td></tr></table></div>    
<div id="table5"> <table border="1"><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td><td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b></td><td><b>Centre de prelevare</b></td><td><b>Centre de transplant</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Târgu Mureș<br />
Str.Molter Karoly Nr. 2, Mureş<br />
Telefon: 0365 430 179<br />
Fax: 0365 430 178</td><td>Institutul de Urgenţă pentru Boli Cardiovasculare şi Transplant Tg. Mureş<br />
Compartiment imunologie de transplant, HLA<br />
Strada Dr. Gh. Marinescu nr. 50, Târgu Mureș, Mureș<br />
Telefon: 0372 653 122<br />
Fax:        0265 215 768<br />
ibcvt-public.sharepoint.com</td><td>Spitalul Clinic Judeţean de Urgenţă Târgu Mureş<br />
Str. Dr. Gh. Marinescu, Nr. 50, Târgu Mureş 540136, Judeţul Mureş<br />
Telefon: 0265 217 235<br />
Fax:       0265 215 768<br />
www.spitjud.ms.ro</td><td>Spitalul Clinic Judeţean de Urgenţă Târgu Mureş<br />
Str. Dr. Gh. Marinescu, Nr. 50, Târgu Mureş 540136, Judeţul Mureş<br />
Telefon: 0265 217 235<br />
Fax:       0265 215 768<br />
www.spitjud.ms.ro</td></table></div>
 <div id="table6"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Brăila<br />
Str. Radu Campiniu Nr. 25, Brăila<br />
Telefon: 0339 401 784<br />
Fax: 0239 611 018</td></tr></table></div>   
 <div id="table7"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Oradea<br />
Str.Loius Pasteur Nr. 30, Bihor<br />
Telefon: 0359 190 815<br />
Fax: 0359 190 815</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table8"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Râmnicul Vâlcea<br />
Str. Gen.Magheru 54, Vâlcea<br />
Telefon: 0350 414 881<br />
Fax: 0350 414 882</td></tr></table></div>    
 <div id="table9"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Satu-Mare<br />
Str. Careiului Nr. 26, Satu Mare<br />
Telefon: 0361 420 905; 0361 420 906</td></tr></table></div>  
 <div id="table10"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Slatina<br />
Str. Ecaterina Teodoroiu nr. 3, Olt<br />
Telefon: 0349 416 499<br />
Fax: 0249 438 011</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table11"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Galați<br />
Str. Regiment 11 Siret , Nr. 48A, Galaţi<br />
Telefon: 0336 401 905; 0336 401 904<br />
Fax: 0336 401 906</td></tr></table></div> 
<div id="table12"> <table border="1"><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td><td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b></td><td><b>Centre de transplant</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din din CRTS Cluj<br />
Str. Nicolae Balcescu Nr. 19, Cluj<br />
Telefon: 0364 417 641; 0364 417 640<br />
Fax: 0264 597 120</td><td>Laboratorul clinic de analize medicale și imunologie<br />
Institutul Clinic de Urologie și Transplant Renal Cluj-Napoca<br />
Strada Clinicilor nr. 4-6, Cluj-Napoca<br />
Telefon: 0264 592 845<br />
Fax:        0264 592 845<br />
www.institut-urologie.ro </td><td>Laboratorul clinic de analize medicale și imunologie<br />
Institutul Clinic de Urologie și Transplant Renal Cluj-Napoca<br />
Strada Clinicilor nr. 4-6, Cluj-Napoca<br />
Telefon: 0264 592 845<br />
Fax:        0264 592 845<br />
www.institut-urologie.ro </td></tr></table></div> 
<div id="table13"> <table border="1"><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td><td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b></td><td><b>Centre de prelevare</b></td><td><b>Centre de transplant</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CRTS Timișoara<br />
Str. Martir Marius Ciopec Nr. 1, Timiş<br />
Telefon: 0356 175 711<br />
Fax: 0256 482 271</td><td>Centrul regional de imunologie de transplant<br />
Spitalul Clinic Judetean de Urgenta “Pius Brînzeu” Timisoara (fostul  Spital Clinic nr.1)<br />
Bulevardul Iosif Bulbuca Nr. 10, Timișoara, Timiș<br />
Telefon: 0356 433 111<br />
Fax:        0256 486 956<br />
www.hosptm.ro</td><td>Spitalul Clinic de Urgenţă pentru Copii “Louis Ţurcanu” Timişoara<br />
Str. Dr. Iosif Nemoianu, Nr. 2, Timişoara 300011, Judeţul Timiş<br />
Telefon: 0256 201 976<br />
Fax:       0256 201 975<br />
www.spitalul-copii-timisoara.info</td><td>Spitalul Clinic de Urgenţă pentru Copii “Louis Ţurcanu” Timişoara<br />
Str. Dr. Iosif Nemoianu, Nr. 2, Timişoara 300011, Judeţul Timiş<br />
Telefon: 0256 201 976<br />
Fax:       0256 201 975<br />
www.spitalul-copii-timisoara.info</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table14"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Brașov<br />
Str.Victor Babeș Nr. 21-22, Braşov<br />
Telefon: 0368 001 124<br />
Fax: 0268 411 735</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table15"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din Institutul Regional de Oncologie Iași<br />
Str.Henri Mathias Berthelot nr. 2-4 , Iaşi<br />
Telefon: 0374 278 810<br />
Fax: 0374278 802</td><td>Laboratorul de imunologie și genetică<br />
Spitalul Clinic de Urgență ”Sfântul Spiridon” Iași<br />
Bulevardul Independentei nr. 1, Iași<br />
Telefon: 0232-240822<br />
Fax:        0232-217781<br />
www.spitalspiridon.ro</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table16"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Ploiești<br />
Str. Vestului Nr. 24A, Prahova<br />
Telefon: 0344 401 012<br />
Fax: 0244 595 517</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table17"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Bacău<br />
Cal. Marasesti, 22, Bacău<br />
Telefon: 0234 535 769<br />
Fax: 0234 570 628</td></tr></table></div> 
 <div id="table18"> <table><tr><td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b></td></tr>
   <tr><td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Slobozia<br />
Str. Decebal Nr. 1, Ialomiţa<br />
Telefon: 0243 233 017</td></tr></table></div> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to remove `href="?bucuresti"` from first row?

Comment: if you can make basic jsfiddle for your scenario it will be helpfull

Comment: i want to be a link in same page thats why i use ?bucuresti

Comment: I think you can do this by giving the href's of your links to the id's of your div's.

For Ex : <a href="#table1">Click 1</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Edit 1

I had to remove the original text because it went over the character limit. I've cleaned up your CSS and HTML a bit, and with this solution there isn't any javascript. If, however, you would like to add in compatibility for browsers that do not support the CSS3 `:target` psuedo element, your code has some description to it now so it would be easier to work with.

```css
td {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.country-wrapper div.table-wrapper {
  display: none;
}
.country-wrapper div.table-wrapper:target {
  display: block;
}
ul.link-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table class="country-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <ul class="link-nav">
        <li><a href="#table1" class="table-link">București</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table3" class="table-link">Covasna</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table4" class="table-link">Craiova</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table5" class="table-link">Târgu Mureş</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table6" class="table-link">Brăila</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table7" class="table-link">Oradea</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table8" class="table-link">Râmnicul Vâlcea</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table9" class="table-link">Satu-Mare</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table10" class="table-link">Slatina</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table11" class="table-link">Galaţi</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table12" class="table-link">Cluj-Napoca</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table13" class="table-link">Timișoara</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table14" class="table-link">Brașov</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table15" class="table-link">Iași</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table16" class="table-link">Ploiești</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table17" class="table-link">Bacău</a>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#table18" class="table-link">Slobozia</a>
        </li>
      </ul>



    </td>
    <td>
      &nbsp;
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="table1" class="table-wrapper">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de prelevare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de transplant</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS București
              <br />Str. Dr. C-tin Caracaş nr. 2-8, Sect. 1, Bucureşti
              <br />Telefon: 031 425 1241
              <br />Fax: 021 319 3162
              <br />
              <br />Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Spitalul Clinic de Urgență București
              <br />Calea Floreasca nr . 8, Sector 1, Bucureşti
              <br />Telefon: 021 599 2300
              <br />Fax: 021 599 2257
              <br />
              <br />Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Spitalul Universitar de Urgență București
              <br />Splaiul Independentei Nr.169, Sector 5, Bucureşti
              <br />Telefon: 021 318 0519
              <br />
              <br />Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din UTS Institutul Clinic Fundeni
              <br />Șoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti
              <br />Telefon: 021 318 0448
              <br />Fax: 021 318 0444</td>
            <td>Laboratorul de histocompatibilitate
              <br />Institutul National de Hematologie Transfuzionala “Prof.Dr.C.T.Nicolau” București
              <br />Strada Constantin Caracaș Nr. 2-8, Sector 1, Bucureșt
              <br />Telefon: 031 425 1230/31/32/33 interior 215
              <br />Fax: 021 319 1779
              <br />Instit. de Hematologie – www.transfuzia.ro
              <br />
              <br />Laboratorul central de referință pentru virusurile transmise prin sânge
              <br />Institutul Național de Hematologie Transfuzională București
              <br />Strada Constantin Caracaș, Nr. 2-8, Sector 1, București
              <br />Telefon: 031 425 1230/47 interior 232
              <br />Instit. de Hematologie – www.transfuzia.ro</td>
            <td>Institutul Clinic Fundeni, Bucureşti
              <br />Şoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti, 022328
              <br />Telefon: 021 275 0700
              <br />Fax: 021 318 0444
              <br />www.icfundeni.ro
            </td>
            <td>Institutul Clinic Fundeni Bucureşti
              <br />Şoseaua Fundeni Nr. 258, Sector 2, Bucureşti, 022328
              <br />Telefon: 021 275 0700
              <br />Fax: 021 318 0444
              <br />www.icfundeni.ro
            </td>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table2" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Arad
              <br />Str. Spitalului Nr. 4, Arad
              <br />Telefon: 0357 432 914; 0357 432 915
              <br />Fax: 0357 432 914; 0357 432 915</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table3" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Covasna
              <br />Str. Banki Donath 15, Covasna
              <br />Telefon: 0367 401 164 ; 0367 401 165
              <br />Fax: 0267 311 980</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table4" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Craiova Str. Tabaci, Nr. 1, Dolj
              <br />Telefon: 0351432 059; 0351 432 060
              <br />Fax: 0251 411 633
              <br />Fax: 0267 311 980</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table5" class="table-wrapper">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de prelevare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de transplant</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Târgu Mureș
              <br />Str.Molter Karoly Nr. 2, Mureş
              <br />Telefon: 0365 430 179
              <br />Fax: 0365 430 178</td>
            <td>Institutul de Urgenţă pentru Boli Cardiovasculare şi Transplant Tg. Mureş
              <br />Compartiment imunologie de transplant, HLA
              <br />Strada Dr. Gh. Marinescu nr. 50, Târgu Mureș, Mureș
              <br />Telefon: 0372 653 122
              <br />Fax: 0265 215 768
              <br />ibcvt-public.sharepoint.com
            </td>
            <td>Spitalul Clinic Judeţean de Urgenţă Târgu Mureş
              <br />Str. Dr. Gh. Marinescu, Nr. 50, Târgu Mureş 540136, Judeţul Mureş
              <br />Telefon: 0265 217 235
              <br />Fax: 0265 215 768
              <br />www.spitjud.ms.ro
            </td>
            <td>Spitalul Clinic Judeţean de Urgenţă Târgu Mureş
              <br />Str. Dr. Gh. Marinescu, Nr. 50, Târgu Mureş 540136, Judeţul Mureş
              <br />Telefon: 0265 217 235
              <br />Fax: 0265 215 768
              <br />www.spitjud.ms.ro
            </td>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table6" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Brăila
              <br />Str. Radu Campiniu Nr. 25, Brăila
              <br />Telefon: 0339 401 784
              <br />Fax: 0239 611 018</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table7" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Oradea
              <br />Str.Loius Pasteur Nr. 30, Bihor
              <br />Telefon: 0359 190 815
              <br />Fax: 0359 190 815</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table8" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Râmnicul Vâlcea
              <br />Str. Gen.Magheru 54, Vâlcea
              <br />Telefon: 0350 414 881
              <br />Fax: 0350 414 882</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table9" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Satu-Mare
              <br />Str. Careiului Nr. 26, Satu Mare
              <br />Telefon: 0361 420 905; 0361 420 906</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table10" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Slatina
              <br />Str. Ecaterina Teodoroiu nr. 3, Olt
              <br />Telefon: 0349 416 499
              <br />Fax: 0249 438 011</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table11" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Galați
              <br />Str. Regiment 11 Siret , Nr. 48A, Galaţi
              <br />Telefon: 0336 401 905; 0336 401 904
              <br />Fax: 0336 401 906</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table12" class="table-wrapper">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de transplant</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din din CRTS Cluj
              <br />Str. Nicolae Balcescu Nr. 19, Cluj
              <br />Telefon: 0364 417 641; 0364 417 640
              <br />Fax: 0264 597 120</td>
            <td>Laboratorul clinic de analize medicale și imunologie
              <br />Institutul Clinic de Urologie și Transplant Renal Cluj-Napoca
              <br />Strada Clinicilor nr. 4-6, Cluj-Napoca
              <br />Telefon: 0264 592 845
              <br />Fax: 0264 592 845
              <br />www.institut-urologie.ro</td>
            <td>Laboratorul clinic de analize medicale și imunologie
              <br />Institutul Clinic de Urologie și Transplant Renal Cluj-Napoca
              <br />Strada Clinicilor nr. 4-6, Cluj-Napoca
              <br />Telefon: 0264 592 845
              <br />Fax: 0264 592 845
              <br />www.institut-urologie.ro</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table13" class="table-wrapper">
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Laboratoare de testare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de prelevare</b>
            </td>
            <td><b>Centre de transplant</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CRTS Timișoara
              <br />Str. Martir Marius Ciopec Nr. 1, Timiş
              <br />Telefon: 0356 175 711
              <br />Fax: 0256 482 271</td>
            <td>Centrul regional de imunologie de transplant
              <br />Spitalul Clinic Judetean de Urgenta “Pius Brînzeu” Timisoara (fostul Spital Clinic nr.1)
              <br />Bulevardul Iosif Bulbuca Nr. 10, Timișoara, Timiș
              <br />Telefon: 0356 433 111
              <br />Fax: 0256 486 956
              <br />www.hosptm.ro
            </td>
            <td>Spitalul Clinic de Urgenţă pentru Copii “Louis Ţurcanu” Timişoara
              <br />Str. Dr. Iosif Nemoianu, Nr. 2, Timişoara 300011, Judeţul Timiş
              <br />Telefon: 0256 201 976
              <br />Fax: 0256 201 975
              <br />www.spitalul-copii-timisoara.info
            </td>
            <td>Spitalul Clinic de Urgenţă pentru Copii “Louis Ţurcanu” Timişoara
              <br />Str. Dr. Iosif Nemoianu, Nr. 2, Timişoara 300011, Judeţul Timiş
              <br />Telefon: 0256 201 976
              <br />Fax: 0256 201 975
              <br />www.spitalul-copii-timisoara.info
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table14" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Brașov
              <br />Str.Victor Babeș Nr. 21-22, Braşov
              <br />Telefon: 0368 001 124
              <br />Fax: 0268 411 735</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table15" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din Institutul Regional de Oncologie Iași
              <br />Str.Henri Mathias Berthelot nr. 2-4 , Iaşi
              <br />Telefon: 0374 278 810
              <br />Fax: 0374278 802</td>
            <td>Laboratorul de imunologie și genetică
              <br />Spitalul Clinic de Urgență ”Sfântul Spiridon” Iași
              <br />Bulevardul Independentei nr. 1, Iași
              <br />Telefon: 0232-240822
              <br />Fax: 0232-217781
              <br />www.spitalspiridon.ro
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table16" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Ploiești
              <br />Str. Vestului Nr. 24A, Prahova
              <br />Telefon: 0344 401 012
              <br />Fax: 0244 595 517</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table17" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Bacău
              <br />Cal. Marasesti, 22, Bacău
              <br />Telefon: 0234 535 769
              <br />Fax: 0234 570 628</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div id="table18" class="table-wrapper">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td><b>Centrele donatorilor de CSH</b>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Centrul donatorilor de celule stem hematopoietice din CTS Slobozia
              <br />Str. Decebal Nr. 1, Ialomiţa
              <br />Telefon: 0243 233 017</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: well thats an anchor with #, i want a link in the same page like href "?table1"

Comment: that link was your problem. without it, users are always going to be redirected to a different page without seeing the table you want displayed. if you want to stay **on the same page** without it reloading, you should use `#table1` instead.

Comment: I have a map and on click of one country will be redirected to table 1 for example, but if new window opens it won't read the #table1 data...

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand.

Comment: i have a page with a country image map and if he clicks on "bucuresti" for example he will be redirected to www.example.com/map#table1 (but the table one is not read the data if is not a page, this is just an anchor with #)

Comment: is that not what the links on the side are for -- to bring up that data?

Comment: yes, but if i acces the direct link for example: www.example.com/#table1 - the data is not showing... only if i click after on the tab...